# Incorporating seasonality in regression #gTrans #rms

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, seasonality, splines

I have been looking into incorporating seasonal effects using the gTrans function in the rms R package. However, I am having some difficulty interpreting the statistical explanation in the document.

As explained here:

https://hbiostat.org/R/rms/gtrans.html#non-spline-basis

**section 6...**

We can make a function called hrm and then provide this to gTrans to model seasonality.

```
hrm <- function(x) {
  z <- cbind(x, slopeChange=pmax(x - 0.5, 0), sin=sin(2*pi*x/0.2), cos=cos(2*pi*x/0.2))
  attr(z, 'nonlinear') <- 2:4
  z
}
h <- ols(y ~ gTrans(x1, hrm))
```

My model is actually a longitudinal logistic regression with additional predictors though I have pasted the code in the document for brevity.

My questions are:

1. I believe that 0.2 is the length of the seasonal cycle. So if my time variable, t, is in days am I correct to replace 0.2 with 365 to allow seasonal cycle to be one year?
2. Am I correct to think of slopeChange, sin and cos just like other variables in the regression (since they will get a regression coeficient), its just that they are transformations of x?
3. Regarding the slopeChange term, I think that it doesnt have any effect for x<0.5 since the new transformed variable (i.e. slopeChange) is always 0. In the example I think 0.5 is the midpoint of x; presumably the modeler sets this point based on theory?  I'm not sure if its helpful to think of it like a knot in a restricted cubic spline?
4. I think that we could also write the slopeChange term as:

   slopeChange=ifelse(x<= 0.5, 0, x-0.5)

However, in both cases we are defining this new transformed x variable to have values between 0 and 5 (assuming maximum x is 1).  I'm wondering WHY this choice of values? For example why not:

```
slopeChange=ifelse(x<= 0.5, 0, x-0.5+1)
```

where we have added the constant 1 on the end. This actually changes the estimated parameter for the variable slopeChange but I don't know why; if we simply add a constant to a predictor (each value in the vector) in a regression, this should not change the estimated parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Take a look at the "real" example here: https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#complex-curve-fitting-example where $x$ is in years and the scaling makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you Professor Harrell! I see in the linked document in your answer that you used a rcs before the sin and cos terms, instead of cbind(x, slopeChange=pmax(x - 0.5, 0),...) as in your gTrans document. That makes more sense to me. I'm assuming that in the gTrans document you were just trying to illustrate how one can add a linear term and a slope change but the scaling was arbitrary and the "proper" way to do it is using a rcs as described in: https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#complex-curve-fitting-example. Is this correct?

Comment: I wouldn't quite word it that way.  It was more of a distinction between a (usually oversimplified) linear spline function and a (usually better fitting) rc spline function.

Comment: OK many thanks for the clarification Professor.

Comment: Note that on this site thanks is expressed by upvoting.